# Realtime colormap from c++ array

Tags: c++, qt, plot, qwt

I'm developing a data acquisition software that stores data from an on-board card and plots it continuously in a producer-consumer way.

What I already have look like this:

Producer:

```
while(true){
    acquire(data);
    signal_consumer();
}
```

Consumer:

```
while(true){
    wait_producer();
    data2file();
}
```

data is an array containing 1 sec. of acquisition.

What I want to add now is another consumer that performs some filter (maybe a fft) and updates a colormap with each acquisition (each data array filtered would be a row of the colormap).

I've read about several plot libraries and decided for qwt. I've taken a look at the examples (realtime and spectrogram) but I couldn't grasp the way it works and how could I make it plot my filtered data array.

Am I using the right tool for the job? is there a  way to use c++ arrays for qwt? If yes, how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools to solve this job, and based on what you have described qwt is definitely a good candidate. Yes, you can use vectors (what you are calling c++ arrays) in qwt. Here is an example:

```
 QwtPlot plot;
 // ... setup plot to taste ...
 std::vector<double> x;
 std::vector<double> y;
 x.push_back(0.0);
 x.push_back(1.0);
 x.push_back(2.0);
 y.push_back(0.0);
 y.push_back(2.0);
 y.push_back(4.0);
 QwtPlotCurve curve("Plot");
 curve.setSamples(&x[0], &y[0], (int)x.size());
 curve.attach(&plot);
```

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot.html

http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html

Comment: But what happens if I want to update that plot with new values in x and y?

Comment: @papanoel87 the "easy" answer is to discard the plot and redraw it with the new set of data. The amount of data you have and how often you want to update the plot will determine whether this is suitable for your application or not.

Comment: @papanoel87 - indeed, I would follow the suggestion above until you run into an actual performance issue. Please mark the answer as solved or let us know if it is not solved yet.